# SQL WITH CTE followed by delete issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just having a strange problem with a SQL statement. I am using a `WITH` statement to collect parent and children rows for a tree structure.

I then want to delete a parent and only their children.

My code is as follows (in a stored procedure):

```
DECLARE @AssignmentIds TABLE
(
  AssignmentIds int
);

with DeleteTree(AssignmentID)
as
(
    select AssignmentID
    from Assignment
    where AssignmentID = @AssignmentID

    union all

    select a.AssignmentID
    from Assignment a
    join DeleteTree d on a.ParentID = d.AssignmentID
)
/* insert results of above with into table var*/
insert into @AssignmentIds 
  select AssignmentID from DeleteTree

/*This select returns the CORRECT Ids!*/
/*SELECT * from @AssignmentIds*/

/*Delete Roster Info*/
delete from [dbo].[Roster] 
where [AssignmentId] in (select AssignmentId from @AssignmentIds)

/*Delete Assignments*/
delete from [dbo].[Assignment] 
where [AssignmentID] in (select AssignmentID from @AssignmentIds)
```

The weird part is that if I run a select on the results of the with, I get correctly a list of the correct assignment ids.

But when I run the `delete` statement, it deletes all the rows in the assignments table, instead of just the Ids found by the with statement!

Comment: Hi Giorgi, yes I checked and there is no cascading delete on rosters table or assignments tables - thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone. But because of the typo in the delete statements at the end, (The column name of the @AssignmentIds table var was mistakenly "AssignmentIds" not "AssignmentId") the SQL Parser was not giving an error, and instead deleting all rows in the roster and assignment tables.

Im still not sure why it would, instead of not deleting anything, but possibly someone else has that answer.

So the lesson I learnt is lookout for typos in delete statements. Otherwise man its scary!